# while loop didn't reset result and Repeat results

Tags: php, loops, smarty

i have 3 tables i was made one query for tow tables 
and the second table in while loop and this table is the problem in result view please
check attachment to unerstand problem 
and this is php code :

```
       $select_all =  mysql_query("SELECT categories.id,cat![enter image description here][1]egories.name,categories.name_en,
categories.block_type,group_fields.ct_id,group_fields.content,group_fields.content_en
 FROM categories LEFT JOIN group_fields
ON categories.block_type=group_fields.id
WHERE categories.home_new='1' ORDER BY sorting ASC ")or die(mysql_error());
while($row_all    = mysql_fetch_array($select_all))
{
  $allcc[]      = $row_all;

  $tblname      =$row_all['id'];
  $select_grp   = $Drweb2->mysql_query("select * from $tblname");
  while($rrc    = $Drweb2->mysql_fetch_array($select_grp))
  {
    $rgcont[] = $rrc;
  }
  $smarty->assign('data',$rgcont);
}
$smarty->assign('allcc',$allcc);
```

and this is smarty html code :

```
{section name=gac loop=$allcc}
{$allcc[gac].content}
{/section}
```

problem example : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOHIg.png

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that the while statement is working, but you're not iterating through the array.

perhaps try:

```
$tblname      = $row_all['id'];
$select_grp   = $Drweb2->mysql_query("select * from $tblname");
$data         = $Drweb2->mysql_fetch_array($select_grp)
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $rgcont[] = $row; // or a specific field name using $row['field_name']
}
```

as for the smarty, can you do this:

```
{section name=gac loop=$allcc}
    {$allcc[gac].content}
    {$allcc[gac].data}
{/section}
```

not sure if that will work, but it's my best guess.

Comment: can u send me html code i think your way is correct please help me

Comment: I am not familiar with smarty html but from the looks of it $allc being passed looks ok since it should contain all the array data added.  why is the $rgcont[] array assigned to  "data" instead of being part of $allc[] array? are you expecting the data to display as part of the array or separately?

Comment: your code is working correctly in php code bu when i try to display it in smarty i can't and it's must to display in smarty and i can pay to solve my problem

Comment: is there another section called "data", because the template i see for the gac does not include the data element you are putting the database response into.

Comment: because this variable "{$allcc[gac].content}" content the section looping for "data" ... 
can u send me ur mail to chat with u please?

Comment: i apologize for the inconvenience, but i am not fluent (or familiar) with smarty, so i may be of little use to you beyond the data query portion. I am sorry.